# how to load or use a Model in a Component File especially in Cakephp 2.0?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

I need to load a Model in a component to save the Data of that related model in that component itself.

> My Component name is **ImagemuploadComponent**

In this Component I want to load the **Attachement** Model.
I've tried the following code but it did't worked. (Which works fine in cakephp 1.3)

```
  $Attachment = ClassRegistry::init('Attachment');
  $this->loadModel('Attachment');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. This will import your model and instantiate.

After this you can perform any operation as controller.

```
App::import('Model','Attachment');
$this->Attachment = &new Attachment();
$this->Attachment->save($your_data);
```

Comment: This answer is a bad one giving false advice for more than one reason:  App::import is deprecated for loading classes and App::uses() should be used and for a model in this case it should be ClassRegistry::init('Attachment'); The question was for 2.0 not 1.3.